# Class group of the cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from exercise 6.3a of Hartshorne.

Let $V$ be a projective variety over a field $k$ of dimension $\geq 1$ that is non-singular in codimension 1. Let $X = C(V)$ be the affine cone over $V$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k$ and let $\overline{X}$ be its projective closure in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_k.$ Let $P \in X$ be the vertex of the cone.

Consider the projection map $\overline{X}-P \rightarrow V.$ It is easy to show that there is a covering of $V$ by open subsets $U_i$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times \mathbb{A}_k^1$ for each $i.$ I want, using this prove that the pullback map $\pi^\ast: Cl (V) \rightarrow Cl(\overline{X}-P)$ is an isomorphism between the class groups.

I can actually prove this using a method that's clearly overkill, namely, using that $\overline{X}-P \rightarrow V$ is a vector bundle over $V,$ and then quoting a theorem from Fulton's "Intersection theory" showing that this induces an isomorphism of the Chow groups $A_{n-1}(V)$ and $A_n(\overline{X}-P).$ But this is certainly not what was intended.

Another method of proof would be to show that the map $Div(V-U_i) \rightarrow Div(\pi^{-1}(V-U_i))$ is surjective and then use a snake lemma proof to finish it off. I think this is true, but I have some concerns since it only requires one $U_i$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times A_i.$

Any help would be welcome.